# Spring-security not logging-in user even when credentials are correct

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Can anyone point out my mistake. I cannot login with a registered user at first I thought it was because I was encrypting the password but even now I have removed encoding the user still cannot login even with plaintext password?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SgaWebApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/sga/app/xml/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/springSgaDb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:com/sga/app/xml/security-context.xml
            classpath:com/sga/app/xml/dao-context.xml
            classpath:com/sga/app/xml/service-context.xml
        </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

My login.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/main.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>SGA-login page</title>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="login">
        <h2 class="customLoginFormHeader">Login with Username and
            Password</h2>

        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
            <p class="errorCustomLogin">Login failed. Please try your
                username/password again.</p>
        </c:if>

        <form name='f'
            action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'
            method='POST' class="loginForm">
            <table>
                <tr class="loginFormTableRow">
                    <td class="tdCustomLogin">Username:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='j_username'
                        class="usernameInputCustomLogin"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="loginFormTableRow">
                    <td class="tdCustomLogin">Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='j_password'
                        class="passwordInputCustomLogin" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="loginFormTableRow">
                    <td class="tdRememberMeHeader">Remember me:</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"
                        name='_spring_security_remember_me' checked="checked"
                        class="rememberMeCustomLogin" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="loginFormTableRow">
                    <td colspan='2'><input type="submit" value="Login"
                        class="customLoginSubmitButton" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My security-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource" id="jdbcUserService" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"
        invalidate-session="true" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/customloginform"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/error"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/register"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/contactus"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied"
        access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/menu"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/roundanalysis"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/roundanalysiserrorpage"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/analysisoutcome"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/viewmystats"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userstats"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/clubstats"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/allstats"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/customloginform"
        default-target-url="/menu" authentication-failure-url="/customloginform?error=true" />
    <security:access-denied-handler
        error-page="/denied" />
    <security:remember-me key="sgaAppKey"
        user-service-ref="jdbcUserService" />
</security:http>
<security:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>
```

And my LoginDAO:

```
@Repository
@Component("usersDAO")
@Transactional
public class UsersDAO {

private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbc;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Session session() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Transactional
public boolean createUser(UserBean user) {
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("username", user.getUsername());
    params.addValue("email", user.getEmail());
    params.addValue("password", user.getPassword());
    params.addValue("forename", user.getForename());
    params.addValue("surname", user.getSurname());
    params.addValue("homeclub", user.getHomeclub());
    params.addValue("authority", user.getAuthority());
    return jdbc
            .update("insert into users (username, email, password, forename, surname, homeclub, authority) values (:username, :email, :password, :forename, :surname, :homeclub, :authority)",
                    params) == 1;
}

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
    this.jdbc = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbc);
}

public boolean exists(String username) {
    return jdbc.queryForObject(
            "select count(*) from users where username=:username",
            new MapSqlParameterSource("username", username), Integer.class) > 0;
}

public List<UserBean> getAllUsers() {
    return jdbc.query("select * from users",
            BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(UserBean.class));
}
```

}

And here is the console output:

```
DEBUG - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG - Executing prepared SQL statement [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]
DEBUG - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG - Executing prepared SQL statement [select username,authority from authorities where username = ?]
DEBUG - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG - User 'Harry12345' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'
DEBUG - User 'Harry12345' not found
DEBUG - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
DEBUG - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@65d201b5
DEBUG - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
DEBUG - Cancelling cookie
DEBUG - Redirecting to /customloginform?error=true
DEBUG - Redirecting to '/SgaWebApp/customloginform?error=true'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log output clearly shows the problem:

```
DEBUG - User 'Harry12345' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'
```

So, it found the user but did not found any authorities associated with him.

Default `<security:jdbc-user-service />` expects at least one authority associated with each user. These authorities should be represented as defined in [37.1 User Schema](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#user-schema).

If you want different representation of user and authority data (e.g. your `authority` field), you need to implement custom `UserDetailsService` instead.

Comment: I believe the problem was that my 'Authorities' table was not being updated/referred to for whatever reason, not sure why as it was previously. Anyway working now and all is good so marked as accepted.